# How can I pass dynamically created controls to JavaScript function from the code behind?

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

I have some dynamically created textboxes and want to add a character counter that shows the remaining characters for each textbox. (Textbox can be singleline or multiline)

In the code behind, I add controls to a list to dynamically display them. The problem is how can I pass the label control to the JavaScript function?:

```
public void SetupTextBox(string id, int textlimit)
{
    TextBox t = new TextBox();
    t.ID = id;
    Label c = new Label();
    c.ID = ...;
    t.Attributes.Add("onkeyup", "Counter(" + c.ClientID + ", this, " + textlimit + ");");

    Controls.Add(t); //add textbox
    Controls.Add(c); // add counter label
}
```

JavaScript:

```
function Counter(labelName, textboxName, maxlimit){
    var lblCounter = document.getElementById(label);
    if(textboxName.value.length > maxlimit)
        textboxName.value = textboxName.value.substring(0, maxlimit);
    else
        lblCounter.innerHTML = maxlimit - textboxName.value.length;
}
```

When I test with the above code, the ID without a quote is passed to the Counter function, but the function does not get called (so, I can't limit the characters entered in the textbox).

When I try the code below, the function gets called, so it can limit the characters entered in the textbox, but the ID is passed with a quote (' ') and `lblCounter` is null.

```
t.Attributes.Add("onkeyup", "Counter('" + c.ClientID + "', this, " + textlimit + ");");
```

How can I pass the counter label and use it in the Counter function?

### Edit

Tried the suggested code.

```
t.Attributes.Add("onkeyup", "Counter(\"" + c.ClientID + "\", this, " + textlimit + ")");
```

It passes the ID without a quote (" ") and the function gets called, but the lblCounter is null.

I may be doing something wrong in the Counter function to get the label with the passed ID.

Comment: If you look at the rendered output in the browser you should see what is going wrong. Hints: quotes, and you don't need `JavaScript: `.

Comment: @AndrewMorton With quotes, it's just passing the string and doesn't work, and without quotes, the javascript function does not get called..

Comment: Please update your question with the new code; I expect it looks something like `t.Attributes.Add("onkeyup", "Counter(\"" + t.ClientId + "\"", this, " + textlimit + ")");` - please note my attempt at escaping the double-quotes.

Comment: @AndrewMorton Thank you for the advice. I updated my question and also tried your code, but I haven't been able to make it work yet. I'll keep working. Again, thank you so much:-)